# Making a dynamic Hyperlink function static

Tags: excel, vba

I had a column of values in column A, all with 6 digit numbers. In order to hyperlink each of these to a folder containing PDF files with the same 6-digit titles, I inserted the following function into cell A2:

`=HYPERLINK("C:\...Project\" & A2 & ".pdf", A2)`

This worked perfectly, and dragging it down through the thousand or so cells created hyperlinks for each entry.

However, now I want to replace column A1 with these new hyperlinks. I thought I could paste-special the column of hyperlinks to remove the dynamic entries in each cells, but this doesn't seem to be possible. I'm sure there's an easier solution. Am I missing something? Can I make column B exist independent of column A before replacing it? Is there a VBA solution?

Comment: Sure, that would be great too

Comment: Looks like I've already been beaten to it below...

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this quickly in vba procedure:

```
Sub CreateHyperlinks()
Dim cl As Range

For Each cl In Range("B1:B100").Cells '## Modify as needed
    cl.Hyperlinks.Add cl, cl.Value, , , cl.Offset(0,-1).Value
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. That works very well. I'm not familiar with the function within in For Loop. What does this do that's different to the worksheet function I used? Thanks a mil!

Comment: The `=HYPERLINK()` formula relies on the address and the friendly name.  In this version he's saying for everything in B1 to B100 make a hyperlink where the address is one column to the left but the friendly name is just the existing value. So instead of creating a column with the hyperlink you're making an existing column into a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

If by any chance anyone wants to do it without VBA, you can replace for example

```
=HYPERLINK(1,2)
```

with

```
<html><a href=1>2
```

but in cases with dynamic formulas it's too complicated because

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\...Project\" & A2 & ".pdf", A2)
```

will be

```
="<html><a href=""C:\...Project\" & A2 & ".pdf"">" & A2
```

and then it has to be copied as text (for example paste the values in Notepad and copy them again in Notepad) before pasting in Excel.